# Article tag not working for some weird reason

Tags: html, css

In my website, after a YouTube iFrame element the h3 tag works but the article tag doesnt work, either on a mobile device or when I make the browser window small.

Here is my HTML & CSS codes for the relevant element:

HTML:

```
<div class="embed-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/example" 
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  <h3 style="position:relative;font-family:minion pro;margin-left:10%;margin-right:40%;padding-top:37%" ;="">Crashing Prank</h3>
    <article style="font-size:100%;margin-left:10%;margin-right:20%;padding-top:1%" ;="">
        Sample article text goes here
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 44%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 12%;
}
```

Comment: I'd give this **two** downvotes if I could.

Comment: Please include the code in your question or in separate fiddle. Show us what you've tried so far. @Paulie_D I got it covered.

Comment: how do you even know your article tag isn't working?

Comment: You need to add the relevant code here.  Optionally, you would create a snippet that repros your issue, and give a visual representation (image?) of what you are trying to accomplish.  Don't ask people to go debug your website, we specifically discourage that.

Comment: @Will yeah it ws too big and i didnt knowwhich part was effecting the article tag

Comment: The issues were fixed, this should be reopened @Paulie_D

Comment: @ulrich the issues were fixed

Comment: @oriol reopen votes wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `overflow:hidden;` from your `embed-container` class, or move the `<article>....</article>` tag outside the `embed-container` div to a separate div.

Comment: Please don't debug other people's websites for them. It encourages help vampires to crap up the place.

Comment: So the downvote is for helping a new SO user fix his issue?? Wow....

Comment: Yep, downvoted for encouraging bad behavior.  If you want to answer people's otf-topic questions, go do it on quora.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274919/downvoting-good-answers-on-bad-questions-helpful-or-not read, follow links, read more.

Comment: lol wow. I have edited his question for him just now because apparently he is a newbie here and I'm sure he could use some help whether it's with his issue or with using SO.

Comment: but its only because we want to learn .. i lost my mind bros! couldnt figure it out .Anyways thank you andrew

Comment: @akkmastr You're welcome man. And please note that Will is right with what he said though so the next time you post a question, remember to  be descriptive, try to post the most relevant code that you think might be causing the issue and also show us what you have tried so far in solving the issue :)

Comment: I have added the relevant codes to your question so just accept the modification to improve the question quality score

Comment: @Will Thanks for the 'trivial edit' lol

Comment: @AndrewLyndem i agree with.. i tried resolving it myself .but just couldnt figure which part of the code was effecting the article and couldnt post the entire as stack overflow wanted the code to be arranged in aparticular manner

Comment: It's ok man.... It's your first time here. Btw, did my answer helped you with your issue?? If yes, then do mark it as the right answer @akkmastr :)